# Making user configurable functions in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have read & understood [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349112/calling-user-defined-function-with-params) that describes how to add parameters to a function. I was wondering how, to make more modular code and plugins slightly more rigid. How would I go about creating `default` parameter values and user `options` within your plugin or your function?

```
$('.pluginAttachment').yourCoolPlugin({
    parameter1: false, //User added
    //the rest of the options
    //Still adds the rest of the default options except above
});
```

I understand that these are variables but am not sure how to intertwine them into the overall function as a `User` parameter that can would take presidence over the default.

Comment: Found the information I needed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200701/jquery-plugin-methods-how-can-i-pass-things-into-them?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how I do it.  I love doing this kind of thing.  Makes the plugin easy for the user and easy to incrementally enhance.

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.yourCoolPlugin = function(options) {
        // Extend our default options with those provided.
        // Note that the first arg to extend is an empty object -
        // this is to keep from updating our "defaults" object.
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.yourCoolPlugin.defaults, options);

        // Now your opts variable wil have either the defaults or values passed by the user.
        DoSomething(opts.parameter1, opts.parameter2);
};

$.yourCoolPlugin.defaults = {
    parameter1:false,
    parameter2:"header"     
};
})(jQuery);
```